# Parse.com-Unable to create classes in Dashboard

Tags: database, parse-platform, http-status-code-500

I accidently clicked "export data" in my parse app settings. I got an email with all of my data, which is great. However, my dashboard now has no classes, and all of the data is gone. In addition, I am unable to create any classes. Therefore, I cannot import the data I exported, so all of my data is useless and now gone. Everytime I try to create a new class (for example if I tried to create a custom class called "asdf"), this happens in the console:

```
dashboard.bundle.js:46 POST https://api.parse.com/1/schemas/asdf 500 (Internal Server Error)c @ dashboard.bundle.js:46
dashboard.bundle.js:46 XHR finished loading: POST "https://api.parse.com/1/schemas/asdf"./
```

I am basically getting a bunch of 500 errors and I have no idea why. Recreating a new app isn't a viable option for me, as I lost an app with a of lot of data and classes.

Comment: i quick made a new app and tried what you did with some data inside, but i can manage to create classes even after export. You should check maybe any `adblock` or try from another browser etc.

Comment: It's only with this specific app i'm unable to create classes. When I create a new app I'm able to create custom classes just fine.

Comment: I just tried on Chrome again without `adblock` and also from Firefox which has no adblock, and I still can't create classes.